# Finding All longest common substring

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying to find ALL longest common substrings between two strings

Supposing that i had computed Suffix array and LCP array correctly as SA[] and LCP[] Is my logic correct or am i missing something?

Here LCP array is between i and i-1 indexes.

Say we have two strings  str=abcabc and str1=bc. I change str= str + '#' + str1.

My suffix array SA[]=[6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2]

And LCP array be=[0,0,3,0,2,2,0,1,1]

What can be a better algorithm to find them ?

Comment: You can easily answer that question yourself, by checking if it works.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually I want to know better algorithm to find all longest common substrings with their indexes in a different vector/array

Comment: In that case I don't think it's a question for SO, but better fitted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. Also, if you want a better algorithm then you should probably actually state so in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a good article on finding all common substrings efficiently, with examples in C. 
http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/algorithm-alley/184404588

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: ok, Dukeling. I am new to SO (I began to (try to)answer questions yesterday) :)

Comment: Dukeling's comment still applies